# Symfony2 Change elements style on every loop made

Tags: php, jquery, css, symfony, twig

So I have a collapsable CSS page for FAQ. With static text everyting works fine. However I am not using static text and I am getting the questions and answers from the database.

So by normal CSS the collapsable FAQ looks like this:

```
          <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <h4><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                  Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a></h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse"  >
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. 
                    <br/><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam elementum varius dapibus. Sed hendrerit porta felis at sollicitudin. 
                    <br/><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam elementum varius dapibus. Sed hendrerit porta felis at sollicitudin. 

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <h4><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                  Collapsible Group Item #2
                </a></h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse"  >
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                  Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

With my for loop in action it looks like this:

```
          <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
          {% for faq in faqs%}
            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <h4><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                  {{faq.question}}
                </a></h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse"  >
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    {{ faq.answer }}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         {% endfor %}
          </div>
```

The problem is that the loop loads the same classes everytime. So no matter what question i press, it will always open the first question.

Is it possible to change the class somehow on every loop? For example:

```
1st loop: id="collapseOne"
2nd loop: id="collapseTwo"
```

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TWIG Loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) for dynamically generate different value as example:

```
<div id="collapse-{{ loop.index }}" class="accordion-body collapse"  >
```

This generate something like:

collapse-1

collapse-2

...

If you need the collapseOne ,  collapseTwo, etc you need to translate the key

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop index (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)

```
{{ loop.index }}
```

For example:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
      {% for faq in faqs%}
        <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <h4><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse{{ loop.index }}">
              {{faq.question}}
            </a></h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse{{ loop.index }}" class="accordion-body collapse"  >
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                {{ faq.answer }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

It makes ids like "collapse1"

Answer (score 0):

try tu use "cycle" in twig (twig API: [cycle](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/cycle.html))

```
    {% for faq in faqs %}
        <div id="{{ cycle(['collapse-1', 'collapse-2']" class="accordion-body collapse"  >
    {% endfor %}
```

I hope it helps you,

Roger